# Xamarin Form TcpConnection using wifi not working when mobile data enabled

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, xamarin, tcpclient

I am writing an application for Android and iOS that read data from a WiFi sensor using System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

```
try
{
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(deviceAddress);

    _tcpClient.Connect(ip, devicePort);

}catch(SocketException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    
}
```

When mobile data is turned off on the smartphone, the connection with the sensor is correct, the data is read.
The problem occurs when Cellular data is turned on. Then the connection is not successful. The exception thrown is:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Connection timed out
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b0] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:892 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEP) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs:346 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress address, System.Int32 port) [0x00048] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs:329
```

Is anybody have similar issue?

Comment: is this a sensor on the local network?  When your phone is using your carrier's network instead of WiFi it won't be able to see things on the local network

Comment: Its a WiFi HotSpot.

Comment: You’re trying to connect to a WiFi hotspot over a cell connection?

Comment: No, Im trying to connect host working on WiFi. When mobile data is off then tcpconnection to that host is ok,but when I trying connect to host when mobile data is on then i Got Exception.

Comment: Host IP is 192.168.0.10, Local IP that i get from device DHCP is 192.168.0.150. And IP for Cellular data is 192.0.0.4

Comment: Natve android tcp client apps connect to this device also when Cellular data is on